# How to use dynamic height of UITableViewCell in auto-layout and move other views to up when bottom view is hidden?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell in xib and its outlets in corresponding UITableViewCell subclass. I am returning height of cell from

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->CGFloat {

return 400

}
```

I need to hide some views based on the data available in each row of the table and bottom view should shifted to top of the cell. When I am hiding view from cell then there is empty space left in place of hidden view & bottom views are not shifting to top part of the cell.

Here is How I am hiding cell view.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    .....
    cell.opetion4.isHidden = true
    cell.opetion3.isHidden = true

}
```

This is my cell.

[image]

After hide 2 middle labels it is looking as follows.

[image]

But I want to remove this empty space and want to shift bottom label to top as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, make the height of **UITableViewCell** to `UITableView.automaticDimension`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Embed all of your questionLabels in a `UIStackView` (vertical) excluding `bottomLabel`. Set **AutoLayoutConstraint** between `UIStackView` and `bottomLabel`.

[image]

Set the `numberOfLines` property of `UILabel`s to 0(zero).

[image]

Set the **Distribution** of the `UIStackView` as `Fill`

[image]

Then, in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method hide the labels. And it will automatically handle the spaces between `UILabel`s

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    cell.questionLabel1.text = labelOneText[indexPath.row]
    cell.questionLabel2.text = labelTwoText[indexPath.row]
    cell.questionLabel3.text = labelThreeText[indexPath.row]

    if labelOneText[indexPath.row] == "" {
        cell.questionLabel1.isHidden = true
    }

    if labelTwoText[indexPath.row] == "" {
        cell.questionLabel2.isHidden = true
    }

    if labelThreeText[indexPath.row] == "" {
        cell.questionLabel3.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

Final Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First I suggest you to set `UITableViewCell` Height to `automatic dimensions` . Attach all the children to one another and last child to `uiview` of xib . Now hiding view does not adjust size of cell so you need to play with height constraint of `uiview` you are hiding .

Make height constraint as strong in `IBOutlet` else it will crash since cells are re-using and `constraint` after setting once will become `nil` . You need to make sure that height constraint are change according to display cell requirement , thats mean for each `cell` maintain some `datasource` that decide to show or hide the view every time when `cellforrowatIndexpath` method called.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->CGFloat {

return UITableView.automaticDimension

}
```

now in cell, put all your views and there siblings which you want to hide/show in `UIstackview (horizontal)`. now if you hide one view, it will be hidden and its apace will be also hidden to no white space will be showing, and no need to handle extra constraints. it will all handled by `stackview`.